# sqlite replacing table iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I currently use a sqlite database for an application in both iOS and Android. I don't wish to move onto CoreData or JSON at present for this application as it works perfectly well with the sqlite database.

However I would like to update one of the tables in the database on my next update.

I presumed this would be something that many people would do but interestingly I've tried searching for answers but getting no results.

So my question is two-fold:
1) Is it possible to replace a table within a sqlite database?
2) If so, how does one go about doing this?

I have no code to share as I can't determine how to even start.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible to replace a table within a sqlite database?

**Yes.**

> 2) If so, how does one go about doing this?

You utilise a means of detecting that a change (an upgrade) is required.

- On Android if using a subclass of [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) then you increase the version number (4th parameter of the super call), in which case the [**onUpgrade**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) method runs, so you override the [**onUpgrade**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) method to handle the update to the table(s).
- This utilises the **user_version** field that is stored in the [**database's header**](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header). In short the SQliteOpenHelper when opening the databases compares the value in the header with the value passed as the 4th parameter. If the passed value is greater than the header value onUpgrade is called. If the values are the same then no such call is made. If the passed value is lower than the value in the header then onDownGrade is called which unless coded results in an exception. *(typically onDowngrade is not utilised)*
- On IOS you could replicate this methodology of comparing a value stored in the user_version extracted via [`PRAGMA user_version`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) and set via the [PRAGMA user_version = ?](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) against a value that indicates a newer version when applicable (i.e. that is not stored in the database). This isn't the only solution

The link above has a brief description which includes a link in relation to SQLite's [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), that itself explains the limitations of the [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) command and has a section that covers alternative solutions. This would apply to both IOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks really useful. It was mainly the SQLite aspect I was struggling to find answers for. Seems there isn’t a direct ‘replace table’ option, but a potential work around with alter table. Thanks again